# Vuetify V-Data-Table footer Add Button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add a button in the v-data-table footer similar to this image.

The issue is I can normally add a button if the table contains data, however, if there's no data, the button doesn't render.

Here's the code:

```
<v-data-table
   class="elevation-1"
   :headers="headers"
   :items="configs"
   item-key="id"
   :items-per-page="10">
      <template v-slot:footer.page-text>
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          class="ma-2"
          @click="buttonCallback">
            Button
          </v-btn>
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: can you please paste the entire data table code?

Comment: To anyone who's still experiencing this issue, update your Vuetify version to 2.3.19. This was a bug that was fixed in that version. 

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.3.19

Answer (score 6):

Here have you a data table example with the button:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="configs"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:footer.page-text>
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          class="ma-2"
          @click="buttonCallback">
            Button
          </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/jairoerazo/pen/wvzYBVW

You can delete the configs array items and the button is rendered.

Comment: Thanks! My issue was that I was using an old vuetify version. This bug was fixed in Vuetify version 2.3.19.

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases/tag/v2.3.19