# Adding a refresh button in the footer of a v-data-table in vue

Tags: html, vue.js

I'd like to get a button in in the footer.

So far I have only succeded in adding a button with removing some page numbers as in this example:[Vuetify V-Data-Table footer Add Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65672175/vuetify-v-data-table-footer-add-button)

So I'd like to add it without removing something from the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I did this just yesterday.
[image]

Try this

```html
<v-card>
    <v-card-text>
        <v-data-table>
        </v-data-table>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-divider />
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        disabled
        block
        depressed
        class="transparent font-weight-bold grey--text pa-2 d-flex align-center justify-start"
      >
        <v-icon>add</v-icon>
        <span>Add new row</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

Comment: Sorry can't manage to get it to work, how do I implement it into my v-data-table?

Comment: But this makes the button go beneath the footer part. I would like it to be a part of the fotter.